# How do I set a custom WordPress update repository?

Tags: php, wordpress, repository

I'm co-authoring a white paper on utilising WordPress as a foundation for a web-app, I would like to change the repository that the core WordPress updates from, the latest additions of automatic updates in 3.7 are very nice, but how would I go about pointing some installations at a custom server repository of mine? I understand the principals behind custom plugin and theme repositories, but updating the core is a necessity.

I think that it queries api.wordpress.org, but what about the server-side code? Is this available anywhere?

If this isn't possible, how would I go about having my WordPress core fetch updates through another manner? Using git/SVN on these other installs won't be an option unfortunately and neither will deploying to them directly, it needs to be via the internal WordPress protocols as this whole paper is about showing that WordPress is a very solid foundation to build upon.

Thanks in advance,
Hamual